# nltk- what is meant by re in the following code

Tags: python, nltk

What does re indicate here

```py
def clean_html(html):
    """
    Remove HTML markup from the given string.
    :param html: the HTML string to be cleaned
    :type html: str
    :rtype: str
    """

    # First we remove inline JavaScript/CSS:
    cleaned = re.sub(r"(?is)<(script|style).*?>.*?(</\1>)", "", html.strip())
    # Then we remove html comments. This has to be done before removing regular
    # tags since comments can contain '>' characters.
    cleaned = re.sub(r"(?s)<!--(.*?)-->[\n]?", "", cleaned)
    # Next we can remove the remaining tags:
    cleaned = re.sub(r"(?s)<.*?>", " ", cleaned)
    # Finally, we deal with whitespace
    cleaned = re.sub(r"&nbsp;", " ", cleaned)
    cleaned = re.sub(r"  ", " ", cleaned)
    cleaned = re.sub(r"  ", " ", cleaned)
    return cleaned.strip()
    raise NotImplementedError ("To remove HTML markup, use BeautifulSoup's get_text() function")
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with nltk. You need to learn python basics at first. Please read about it here https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Please read the regular expression docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#

Answer (score 3):

`re` is a module that provides regular expression matching operations similar to those found in Perl. It provides a set of functions that you can call through re.{function_name} to deal with regular expressions. Have a look at: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html